# Querying Android Groups table very slow

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

A single query to the Groups table takes around 5 minutes despite the table only having 15 rows and despite specifying a projection of only 3 columns.

Is there some reason this might be so slow? Does Android block access to this table while other apps are accessing it, for example? Is there a better way to get information about groups?

Here is an example of a section of code that takes upwards of 5 minutes to execute (note that here I have not included a query or projection, but it is no slower than when I do):

```
ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
resolver.query(android.provider.ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,
               null,
               null,
               null,
               null);
```

Comment: I haven't seen a groups query so slow, it should take less then a second. try with selection `Groups.DELETED + "=0 AND " + Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE + "=1"`, see if it helps.

Comment: how are you counting the time the query took? are you waiting for results to be displayed on screen, or are you measuring in the log? I'd suggest adding a log message before and after the query line and see the diff in the timestamps

Comment: I'm already measuring the time by looking at the timestamps of logs immediately before and after. I have tried an even narrower selection - selecting on specific values of `Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE` and `Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME` - but this is just as slow.

Comment: well, we have a similar query in production, and I get measurements in my analytics, and they're ~10-20ms so maybe you have a corrupt Groups table or something. I'd suggest trying a different device, using a different contacts account preferably

Comment: I had come to the same conclusion. Wiping the Android contacts storage makes the query time negligible.

Answer (score 0):

*(Turning the comment into a proper answer)*

Similar query in our production app reports timing of ~10-20ms.
Maybe you have a corrupt `Groups` table.

I'd suggest trying a different device, using a different contacts account preferably.